# Is there a sbt-native-packager option equivalent to sbt-pack packMain?

Tags: sbt-native-packager

I have a scala application library with several main classes.
When running `sbt stage`, sbt correctly creates bash scripts per main class that I have but with pre-defined names (taken from each class name).
I would like to control the name of the bash script and the JVM opts passed to each one.

For example: given two main classes: FooBar and BarFoo
I get bin/foo-bar and bin/bar-foo respectively.

I would like to somehow pass a map like

```
mainClasses := Map(
  "newFooBar" -> "com.example.FooBar",
  "newBarFoo" -> "com.example.BarFoo"
)

mainClassesJVM := Map(
  "newFooBar" -> "-Xmx512m",
  "newBarFoo" -> "-Xmx2g"
)
```

I found an sbt plugin called [sbt-pack](https://github.com/xerial/sbt-pack) that does what I'm trying to achieve but I was wondering if I could achieve the same only with the sbt-native-packager plugin.

Example using sbt-pack plugin:

```
// [Optional] Specify mappings from program name -> Main class (full package path). If no value is set, it will find main classes 
automatically
packMain := Map(
  "newFooBar" -> "com.example.FooBar",
  "newBarFoo" -> "com.example.BarFoo"
)

// [Optional] JVM options of scripts (program name -> Seq(JVM 
option, ...))
packJvmOpts := Map(
  "newFooBar" -> "-Xmx512m",
  "newBarFoo" -> "-Xmx2g"
)
```

Does anyone know if there is an option to achieve the above using only sbt-native-packager?

Comment: Unfortunately there is not. You can open an issue ( or better a PR ) on the native packager GitHub repository.